# How to get logs from android application with java code?

Tags: android, logging, runtime, adb, exec

I google a lot and found only this approach:

```
String cmd = String.format("logcat -d '%s:I' '*:S'", Schema.TAG);
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( 
        new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    builder.append(line);
    builder.append(separator);
}
```

But it's not work well. I get an empty string or a small part of logs  when execute this command.

Could you suggest how I can get the logs form device, like adb at PC.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Log.d("===============>>>","Your String");
```

in your android monitor search for this  "===============>>>"

that's it